# Buttons, scroll locking, transitions and unusual code error

Tags: html, css, scroll, syntax, transition

I'm having trouble with my code with my CSS stylesheet and HTML index coding. I only have one problem and that is my CSS stylesheet isn't letting me place a `div` class into it. I'm using the free Brackets software which includes syntax highlighting and it's coming up red which is an error. Here is a picture of it:

http://i58.tinypic.com/ju97cl.png

As you can see in that picture, I've boxed around the place where it's disallowing me to place the div class into the stylsheet in **white**. I've given a working example with the **blue** box so I'm confused to why it's doing this.

---

My main question for you today is how do I create buttons directly in the center on the side of my page with CSS or however possible and how to edit these buttons like adding hover animations, visual looks etc? (I'm new to this by the way) Also, I want to lock the scrolling of my page in a certain area like in the picture described:

http://i62.tinypic.com/wmbyw.png

---

Lastly, I wish to ask how to make my content on the white area transition by sliding to the side for when I click a button to go onto the next page. However possible I would really appreciate if somebody gives me the time for this. Sadly I can't give another image because I don't have 10 reputation. so I hope you can make out what I'm trying to say.

---

I will be so grateful to anyone who helps me with this.

Comment: a class name of `transitions` is not a good idea because there is a style called `transition` in CSS3.

Comment: Even if I change it to any other class name, it is still highlighted red?

Comment: Your `.right-menu` class does not have a closing bracket.

Comment: Ohh that solved that problem, thank you haha - sorry

Comment: To prevent your black bars from moving, add a `position: fixed` to the element.

Comment: give me some up votes man ;)

Comment: Nono it's not the black bars moving, I want the page  to be in a fixed position, take a look at my code and you'll see what I mean because I've sectioned off a lot of the page on the top and bottom in black because I only want a small vertical section to put my content on. http://jsfiddle.net/8x0oapdk/

Comment: `body {overflow: hidden;}` would prevent scrolling of the document body

Comment: Not letting me upvote you btw and I'll try the overflow one sec

Comment: How do would i position the overflow to a certain part of the page

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, Do you mean apply the overflow to a specific element?

Comment: Yeah so what I mean is if I can make it only lock on a certain part of the page

Comment: So what your saying is if the user is scrolling through the document and gets to a certain part you want to lock the page down?

Comment: Kind of but what I mean is I want to lock it to a certain part of the page, no scrolling whatsoever. If you look at the images I put up, you see the way the black borders are with the white space in the middle? I just want to lock it like that with no scrolling since I had to make a big portion of the header and footer black

Comment: So you want the top and bottom black border fixed(non-movable even when scrolling through the document)? but still have the content in the white scrollable?

Comment: Nothing scrollable. Just literally the page to have that. Black borders with a white section just like the pictures

Comment: Do you want to create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for the code you already have and then post the link here?

Comment: Yeah sure > http://jsfiddle.net/5h3q42tL/1/ as you can see a lot of the header and footer are black

Comment: How is this -> http://jsfiddle.net/v6mwgbvm/

Comment: One last thing, how do I add buttons like this on my friends website? I just want them on the side like that. Should I use '<ul>' or anything I just want them positioned the same. Last thing I'll pick your brains for I'm sorry. http://jsfiddle.net/5pge077u/

Comment: are you referring to the subscribe button right next to the email?

Comment: Nono if you look on the right you can see four grey dots on the center right of the page of which you hover over changes. Just want buttons in the same position, I'll figure myself from there on what to do.

Comment: Try this -> http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MYqeNL

Comment: Yeah, so how do I add this but with external files?

Comment: Take all the javascript code and put it in a file `yourFileName.js`. Then take all the CSS in put it in a file `yourFileName.css`. Then in the **head section of your document** create access to your external files by `<script src="path_to_your_file/yourFileName.js"></script>` for your js file and `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path_to_your_file/yourFileName.css">`

Comment: Really appreciate your time. So if I take the time to learn with jQuery and everything will it be possible to shift all my content like I wanted to?

Comment: Yeah, you can use regular javascript to do what you want or jQuery. For beginners, jQuery is the recommended approach to programming.  Here is a very good tutorial to get you started -> http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp

Comment: Before I go, where will I position other content in order to shift it? Could I just link different pages? and when I do will I have to create a seperate index.html for every time it shifts? and how do I change the size of the buttons on the side?

Comment: Try this -> codepen.io/anon/pen/MYqeNL   ....changing the button size can be done by changing the font-size in the `.buttons ul li` class

Comment: Thanks man I really appreciate your time. You're an absolute legend.

Comment: Really sorry one more thing, trying to do a hover effect over one button but it's not working lol. I tried `.b1:hover { background: black; }` @BeastModeJoe

Comment: Refer to my previous codepen link. I think however i need to register for it to work correctly. SImilar to this -> http://jsfiddle.net/S4TMS/

Comment: If I do the `buttons` Id it makes the whole `div` black - I just want to have the circle to turn black. I named my different buttons `b1 b2 b3 b4` and if I type `.b1 hover: { background-color: black }` it doesn't do anything

Comment: in your css, if you are referring to an element's id you need to use `#elementId {background-color: black}`. If you are refering to an element's class name you need to use `.elementClassName {background-color: black}`. Basically one is referenced with a . and the other with a #

Comment: I tried referring to the ID and nothing happened I used `#b1:hover { background-color: black; }`  and still nothing. Do I need to add `ul` and `li` ?

Comment: Here you go -> http://jsfiddle.net/mf73h537/

Comment: Brilliant, legend man thank you loads

Comment: Well apparently my buttons don't want to appear no more, heres my code - I removed the JavaScript because I'll add that later. http://jsfiddle.net/fandtmL9/

Comment: here you go -> http://jsfiddle.net/fandtmL9/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off you need to close your `.right-menu` class with a `}`.

For effects and animations check out w3schools:
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp - transistion property
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp - animations

Centering in CSS can be done with `text-align: center` or `margin-left:auto; margin-right: auto`.

To prevent scrolling of the body do `body {overflow:hidden}`

For sliding page content refer to my links above or checkout jQuery
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_slide.asp

Comment: How do I have an external jQuery file to use and how to link to it?

Comment: [This](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide) explains a lot of it. But in general make sure you put `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>` and `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>` in the `head` section of your document.

Comment: Appreciated! I'll check it out now.